# I want to send two parameters using href through anchor tag in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

```
<a href="@Href("~/Colleges/Details/"+item.Id, item.CountryId)"></a>
```

This code is not hitting the action method. Can you suggest the correct code?

`College` is my controller and `Details` is my action name.

Comment: `<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Colleges", new { id = item.Id, yourCountryIdParam = item.CountryId })"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line of code:

```
<a href="@Href("~/Colleges/Details/"+item.Id, item.CountryId)"></a>
```

With this line of code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Details","Details","Colleges",new { id = item.Id, CountryId = item.CountryId },null)
```

Hopefully, your action method header in Colleges controller looks something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Details(int id, int countryId)
```

Goodluck!